# How do I assign index like this after groupby pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, analytics

I have this Dataset

[DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLBg1.png)

I want Output Where, every Accession Number has S.no which will assign the values, for eg: Accesssion Number -0001754960-22-000233 will have S.no as 1 for all rows, Next Accession will have 2 for all it's rows and so on.

Somewhat like this:

[EXPECTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aJAj.png)

df5['Index']=df5.groupby('Accession Number')['Accession Number'].transform('count')

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

Lets do factorize to identify distinct values in accession number

```
df['S.No'] = df['Accession Number'].factorize()[0] + 1
```